# Does "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" help me against if someone points their domain to my server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cors

Maybe I misunderstood how to fully implement CORS in my server.

Given this screenshot of a request done via Chrome.

[image]

We can see that the we are visiting the site `shakh.photography`, the request URL is a POST ajax request towards `/api/get-videos/` but the response contains a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that mentions a totally different domain.

Even though the webserver respons with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, it is ignored by the browser. Everything still works.

I thought only setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` was sufficient to only allow requests coming from the specified origin.

What have I missed?

Until it's fixed, this situation is testable by visiting shakh.photography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy only stops a site from reading a cross origin Ajax response. This protects against a user's cookies being used by an attacking site to take data from your site using the authority of the user.

CORS allows you to selectively *weaken* the Same Origin Policy, it isn't used to strengthen it.

> We can see that the we are visiting the site shakh.photography, the
>   request URL is a POST ajax request towards /api/get-videos/ but the
>   response contains a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that mentions a
>   totally different domain.
>
> Even though the webserver respons with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   header, it is ignored by the browser. Everything still works.

Yes. This is normal. The request is from Site A to Site A. None of the cookies or other credentials the user might have to Site B are available to the Site A (the browser sandboxes them from each other). You simply have a server which responds to both URLs with the same data.

A third party could do that, but they couldn't do it for just your API (except via a proxy, which is a different issue, with even fewer security implications). They'd have to make the whole site available under the other hostname, this shouldn't cause any security worries.

If you don't want that, then configure your server so that it uses Virtual Name Hosting and delivers different sets of content based on the Host header in the request.

Answer (score 2):

The request is going to same-origin i.e. shakh.photography/api/.. hence no `OPTIONS` preflight being sent.

If the request were send from some third party's webpage say third.party then browser would send `OPTIONS` and server would check for its origin policy and return `error` as only `gamezelle.com` is allowed as of now.
If it were sent from `gamezelle.com` the response would be `OK` and then browser would send subsequent request.

Comment: Ah ok. I still want to disallow shakh.protography to send/request things from the server though.

Comment: Same origin is allowed always, you could check for the origin and return false i guess.

Comment: What do you mean same origin is allowed?

You mean that the CORS headers do not prevent if someone redirects their own domain to my webserver?

Comment: same origin means the request is being sent by http ://a to http: //a/b/c. 
For same origin policy to be applied the protocol hostname and port number should match. In your case shakh.photo is allowed to access shakh.photo/api/..

Comment: By redirection essentially your site will be served, so no cross domain again

Comment: So how do I prevent someone to redirect their domain to my webserver - any suggestions, as in the example above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127044/discussion-between-avck-and-corgrath).